# How to use this: array[0..x] of byte?

Tags: delphi

I have this piece of code.
The BufferAddress was initially of PByteArray type.
However, PByteArray is limited to 32768 elements but I need more than than.

I don't need at run time what is the maximum limit, so I defined TLargeArrayOfBytes from 0 to 2GB. There is a nicer way to do it?

```
function TBufferedStream.Read(VAR aBuffer; Count: Integer): Longint;
TYPE
   TLargeArrayOfBytes = array[0..2000000000] of Byte;
   PArrayOfBytes = ^TLargeArrayOfBytes;
VAR
   BufferAddress: PArrayOfBytes;       // it was PByteArray
begin
 ...

 { Then refill buffer... }
 FillReadBuffer;

 { ...and continue reading }
 BufferAddress:= @TLargeArrayOfBytes(aBuffer);
 Result:= Result+ ReadFromBuffer(BufferAddress[Result], Count- Result);  { Read from RAM buffer }
end;
```

---

Delphi 7

Comment: I think I'd just use a PByte and advance it with inc().

Comment: Luckily, you've managed to define it as roughly 2GB, not 2TB. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your definition, the only suggestion is you can use the `MaxInt` const.

```
type
   TLargeArrayOfBytes = array[0..MaxInt-1] of Byte;
```

or maybe the [`SysUtils.TBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TBytes) type

Comment: MaxInt-1 sound good. I cannot find TBytes in Delphi 7. Thanks.

Comment: Altar, TBytes is simply `array of Byte`. If you use that, you'll need to change the type of the `ABuffer` argument. *Don't* just type-cast it to `TBytes` because a simple pointer isn't the same as a dynamic array.

Answer (score 3):

PByteArray isn't *really* limited to that many bytes. It can point to an array of *any* size. The only problem comes if you have range checking enabled when you apply the bracket operator to the array pointer. Then the compiler checks that the index is within the bounds of the *declared* type, regardless of how many bytes the pointer really points at. Disable range checking before such an expression and then turn it back on afterward.

```
BufferAddress:= PByteArray(@aBuffer);
{$R-}
// Read from RAM buffer
Result := Result + ReadFromBuffer(BufferAddress[Result], Count - Result);
{$R+}
```

Comment: Yes. I know (although it took me a while until I realized that PByteArray is limited to 32768). ERangeCheck error that I got was exactly on that line and it was because of Result was indeed bigger than 32768. I just wanted to find a the most elegant way. I always try to stay away from compiler directives such as $R- (even if temporary). Thanks anyway.

Comment: This technique is used extensively in the Delphi VCL/RTL code, e.g. Classes.TList - before Delphi 4 introduced dynamic arrays this was the usual way of having resizeable arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Using the POINTERMATH directive you don't need to declare types of pointer to array.

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  P : PByte;
begin
  GetMem(P,1000);

  P^ := 42;      //Access first/current element
  P[999] := 42;  //Access last element

  FreeMem(P);
end;
```

Comment: [Error] zzz.pas(77): Invalid compiler directive: 'POINTERMATH'

Comment: Apparently this directive was introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: but question was for Delphi 7

Comment: The question was edited after I posted this answer so the "Delphi 7" was not part of the question. And the pointermath directive is a useful feature that can be useful to know. So I think it is unnecessary of you to downvote this answer one year after it was posted.